# What econometrics method is better for the analysis?

Tags: econometrics, multivariate-analysis, panel-data, instrumental-variables

I need some tips and tricks to figure out what would be an appropriate econometric method to find causal relationships between $x₁$ and $Y$ in my model $Y = α + β₁x₁ + β₂x₂ + \dotsm + βᵣxᵣ + ε$

where x₁ is the predictor variable, which addresses exclusion restriction and exogeneity criteria.

However,  x₁ doesn't change over time; the rest of the data are cross-sectional time series.
Can I use Fixed Effects Panel Data Analysis?

Comment: Yes. Wooldrige's book is the academic bible for these topics https://www.google.com/books/edition/Econometric_Analysis_of_Cross_Section_an/yov6AQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0 but it's based on sanitized toy data. For a more applied approach try Pesaran's tome https://www.google.com/books/edition/Time_Series_and_Panel_Data_Econometrics/MsOPCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: @Roe please provide more context. Is $x_1$ observed? Are you remaining covariates $x_{2:r}$ observed? If you're considering instrumental variable estimation, do you have a valid instrument?

Comment: @Durden Yes, 1 is observed and all the remaining covariates are observed. I don't plan to use an instrument.